# How to select city based on city name in mat-option-text?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium2, xpath

I need to find a specific city from a drop down list. I have tried using the xpath but the id number for the city keeps changing. The element from the website is below:

```
 <mat-option role="option" class="mat-option mat-focus-indicator mat-active ng-tns-c88-11 ng-star-inserted mat-selected" id="mat-option-14" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false" style="" aria-selected="true"><!----><span class="mat-option-text"> Melbourne </span><!----><div mat-ripple="" class="mat-ripple mat-option-ripple"></div></mat-option>
```

My code:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="mat-option-14"]/span'))).click()
```

The code works only when the id is 14 but it can be any number. Can I select by the city name instead somehow? THanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can select the city by name using the text() function in XPath. Here's an example:

```
city_name = "Melbourne"
driver.find_element_by_xpath(f"//mat-option//span[text()='{city_name}']").click()
```

This will locate the span element that contains the city name and click on the corresponding mat-option element. Note that we're using an f-string to include the city_name variable in the XPath expression.

You can also locate the mat-option element based on the id attribute instead of the text. Here is an example code using find_element_by_css_selector method:

```
city_name = "mat-option-21"
option_element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(f"mat-option[id^='mat-option-'][id$='-{city_name}']")

# Click on the option element to select the city
option_element.click()
```